# edit PostgreSQL database from django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

i've created my database in postgresql using models in django .
Now i need to add some columns in my tables ,so i edited my models but it keeps showing me errors in my admin interface

Comment: Did you migrate the database?

Comment: And could you be more specific about what "errors in the admin interface" means for you?

Comment: yes i tried migrating but it asking me to add a default value for columns ,is it possible to do it without adding a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

If it is asking for default values, give those default values.
Finally run the command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```